# WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 Mediation Tracer

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

recently I have found out that the brandnew ESB 5.0.0 has no mediation tracer. I was a quite usefull feature that seems to be missed. How can I check this usefull mediation tracer information in ESB 5.0.0? Can I install the mediation tracer as a new feature again?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Carbon features to your product. There are two ways to do this, UI or file based.

1. Use the [Feature Manager UI](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon440/Installing+Features+via+the+UI). Search and install the mediation tracer feature. (You may want to untick group by categories!)
2. Use the [carbon-p2-plugin](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon4410/Using+the+Carbon+P2+Plugin#UsingtheCarbonP2Plugin-p2-profile-gen) maven plugin. Create a stub pom file, and add the maven plugin configuration mentioned there. You can use the default values for all the configuration files.

Under the `<features>` section, specify the mediation tracer feature.

```
 <feature>
  <id>org.wso2.carbon.mediation.tracer.feature.group</id>
  <version>${carbon.mediation.version}</version>
 </feature>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use WSO2 ESB Analytics, please check this post https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Monitoring+WSO2+ESB+with+WSO2+ESB+Analytics

Comment: Thanks for your help Ernesto. I know that options, but some customers have migrated to ESB 5.0.0 and they do not have WSO2 AS installed. Besides, in same cases, they refuse to install new components, so that is why I look for a way to add the old mediation tracer feaure, if possible.

Comment: You can install the Mediation tracer old version using the feature manager. Or via the file based option This is the artifact you need `<featureArtifactDef>org.wso2.carbon.mediation:org.wso2.carbon.mediation.tracer.feature:${carbon.mediation.version}</featureArtifactDef>`